# How to create dynamic variable with get dynamic data from json

Tags: javascript, variables, dynamic-variables

I have dynamic price change table, and I want to change my price list from data json dynamically,

I want to get **data.Items.Onelow**  and **data.Items.Onehigh** values from json data with dynamic variable;
But I have problem; My codes under below.

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "data.json",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {

            var a = ["One", "Two"];
            a.forEach(function(entry) {


            var entry_data_low = data.Items.entry+low; // HERE Problem
            var entry_data_high = data.Items.entry+high; // HERE Problem




            });




        }
    },2000);

      });
    });
```

Comment: "A problem" being, `low` and `high` are undefined, I guess?

Comment: jeremy Thile yes

Comment: Well, define them, then :)

Answer (score 1):

You should replace this line from

```
var entry_data_low = data.Items.entry+low; // HERE Problem
var entry_data_high = data.Items.entry+high; // HERE Problem
```

to

```
var entry_data_low = data.Items.entry + "low";
var entry_data_high = data.Items.entry + "high";
```

considering object property is as `data.Items.Onelow` and `data.Items.Twolow`.

Comment: says undefinedlow undefined high

Comment: after using string notation it should not say so. Try this `data.Items[entry+"low"]`